# Parsing pom.xml for dependencies returns error - Argument 'element' has incorrect type

Tags: python-3.x, xml, parsing, pom.xml

I am trying to retrieve all the dependencies from a pom.xml file but I ran into this error and cant see to figure it out.

*Notes -* The pom file is in the directory of the code and ive ran it with different pom files and same outcome.

My code

```
from lxml import etree
from collections import defaultdict

root = etree.parse('pom.xml') 
tree = etree.ElementTree(root)

depend = tree.xpath("//*[local-name()='dependency']")
dependencyInfo = defaultdict(dict)

for dep in depend:
    infoList = []
    for child in dep.getchildren():
        infoList.append(child.tag.split('}')[1])
        infoList.append(child.text)


    dependencyInfo[infoList[1]].update({infoList[2] : infoList[3],infoList[4] : infoList[5]})

dependencyInfo
```

The error

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "pomToExcel.py", line 7, in <module>
    tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
TypeError: Argument 'element' has incorrect type (expected lxml.etree._Element, got lxml.etree._ElementTree)
```

Any direction I can take to fix this error would be awesome.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual boilerplate is:

```
tree = etree.parse('pom.xml') 
root = tree.getroot()
```

and from there:

```
depend = root.xpath("//*[local-name()='dependency']")
```

etc. Try it and see if it works.

Comment: Quick question, would you happen to know why if there is multiple groupId with the same name it skips all of them and only outputs the last one?